# What do bad infit and outfit in dichotomous Rasch model signify?

Tags: psychometrics, item-response-theory, rasch, item-analysis

I'm really a beginner with Psychometry. We've just started psychometry in our college and I've used software Jamovi for that purpose.

Working with Dichotomous Rasch models to asses a Multiple choice questions with single best answer based test, I want to know what is the implication of bad infit and outfit square means? I mean what do they signify?

There is a related [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1EmaqrAInck) that says that items with those whose values fall outside of (0.6-1.4) [others say (0.7-1.3)] are bad and we need consider removing them, but it doesn't say what does OUT and  IN signify here, I mean what are the exact pathologies related to each?

I tried surfing the web for that and the best I found is this site:

https://www.rasch.org/rmt/rmt162f.htm

However, still the matter is obscure to me.

Can this be explained in somehow easy and intuitive manner? Is there an open source on easily and intuitively understanding those?